# Speed/Duplex auto-negotiation randomly just stopped working

Tags: networking, internet

Today my internet suddenly stopped working and the network adapter started cycling between "Network cable unplugged" and "enabled".

It was working fine on "auto negotiation" but for some reason it wont connect to the internet.

I tried and 10 mbps full duplex is the only setting that worked. However, now the internet is a lot slower than it used to be.

What causes auto-negotiation to suddenly stop working?

MY network adapter is Intel(R) 82567LF-2 Gigabit Network Connection

Comment: Perhaps you need a new ethernet cable.

Comment: ... or a new NIC because if it's not the cable then it's a partially defective NIC.